Formatting Text Overflow to the Right in Centre Aligned Cells
I'm working in the latest excel, with cells that have center aligned text, and output a string of numbers, as text, via a formula. When the cells overflow, I want them to overflow into the (empty) cells on the right hand side. However, they only overflow to the right when the text they contain is aligned to the left.
With center alignment on the text, the text overflows to the right just fine, but it also overflows to the left, resulting in some text being hidden behind the cells on the left hand side (because those cells aren't empty).
Is there a way to have text center aligned, until the circumstance when the text is going to overflow, when it then becomes left aligned, and thus overflows out of the right side only?
Thanks for any help, and sorry if the answer is obvious!

By definition alignment also affects the overflow into empty neighboring cells. You can't mix these settings. Wether or not the text is generated by a formula does not matter.


You can try with conditional formatting. Only you can't do it exactly as you wanted, because you can't set centering with conditional formatting.
You can only use the format code to move the text to the right edge of the cell if it is short. You can estimate the width of a cell using the CELL("width",address) function.
The condition in conditional formatting would be (as in the screenshot):
=LEN(J1)<CELL("width",J1)

And in the numberformat, use the format code:
* @
(there is a space in the middle).
If the formatting condition is not met, the text remains at the left edge of the cell by default.

